# Is it a good idea to have two versions of jquery-ui library : One with core and other with all components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

We are trying to adapt to using widgets from jquery-ui for most of our functionality. It gives lot of OOP like features and ease of extension. The downside is the jquery-ui library comes with other baggage and in-built widgets that we don't need in some pages. No doubt our project uses  widgets from jquery-ui but in some cases we just need Core and Widget components to write our custom widgets. So my question : Is it worthwhile to have two versions of jquery-ui library one just with Core and other will Core + components we use across the project ? The idea is to just use a lighter jquery-ui-core in pages that have our custom widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to just include the whole script to begin with because with proper server setup, it will be cached from there on out anyway.

An alternative would be to use a requirejs-like setup where you included the components as needed with their dependencies rather than a core+widget version and a core+all version.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to have a single file. Maybe i was looking for a performance gain with a smaller Core widget js...but it shouldn't make a significant difference... Usually # of http requests are more of a problem than the size of the response